# AS3 Load external image online

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I would like to load an external image to a flashwebsite.
I do this using a Loader.

Here's my code.

```
private function init():void
{
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoaded);
    loader.load(new URLRequest(_feed.fromPicture));
}

private function imageLoaded(evt:Event):void
{
    var loaderInfo:LoaderInfo = evt.target as LoaderInfo;
    dispObj = loaderInfo.content;
    this.addChild(dispObj);   
}
```

When I test the swf offline, it works. But when I put everything online and I browse to the HTML file, it doesn't load the images anymore.

What do I have to do to load external images online?

Thanks,

Vincent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer. I had to use an proxy to load my images from an other domain.
Like this: http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/quick-tip-using-a-php-proxy-to-load-assets-into-flash/

Answer (score 0):

This code should work both off- and online.  If your pictures don't load, there must be some other problem.  Perhaps `_feed.fromPicture` was not set correctly, or your file paths behave differently.  Do you have the [Flash content debugger plugin](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) installed?  If not, do so.  Then [set up your flashlog](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/26/debugging-flex-applications-with-mmcfg-and-flashlogtxt/) and check the output for error messages.

Comment: This is the url of my image http://a2.twimg.com/profile_images/1159806756/gdm_normal.png

Comment: What about the rest of my answer?  Do you use the content debugger plugin?  Also, can you post the part of your program where _feed.fromPicture is set?

Answer (score 0):

Is the image you try to load on the same domain as your application? If not, you have to add your domain to the crossdomain.xml file on the server where you try to load the image from.

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html

Rob

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-access-from domain="*" />
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy> -> this is my crossdomain.xml